# Find children of the process

Tags: process, top, ps, pstree

is there any way to know, who are children of the specific process ? for example those children which their parent ID is foo ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are looking for the [`pstree`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/pstree.1.html) command.
`pstree` by itself will list all the processes in a tree form (like `lsblk` does). You can use the `-p` flag to get the PIDs listed as well, and the `-s` to show parent process as well:

```
$ pstree -p 602
udisksd(602)-+-{cleanup}(607)
             |-{gdbus}(605)
             |-{gmain}(603)
             `-{probing-thread}(606)
```

---

A (probably) POSIX-compliant way of getting the child PIDs (that I'd mentioned in the comments elsewhere):

```
ps -o ppid= -o pid= -A | awk '$1 == <some pid>{print $2}'
```

This tells [`ps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ps.1posix.html) to write the parent PID and PID of all processes (without headings), and then uses [`awk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/awk) to see which lines have the given PID in the first field (the parent PID), and prints the corresponding second field (the child PID).

Answer (score 13):

If you just want to see the immediate children of a process whose PID is `123` you can use the `ps` command's `--ppid` option:

```
ps --ppid 123
```

You can combine that with the `pidof` command to get the children of a process by name i.e. given a process called `foo`

```
ps --ppid $(pidof foo)
```

Answer (score 10):

Another option is, to use **System Monitor** (comes pre-installed). In SM Menubar mark "Dependencies" option, under "View", to have a visual feedback, showing parent and children process(es) like show in the screenshot below.

I prefer the CL (Command Line) myself and suggest, that those who use Linux, in this case Ubuntu on a daily basis, wisely invest their time in learning the basic commands, over GUI Applications or at least are able to master both to a certain degree!

[image]
[image]

Comment: OT: What theme is that?

Comment: I use Ubuntu + GnomeShell 3.2.1 The theme is called "AdwaitaDark" which is a GTK3 theme, but it is customized and not available, like you see it in the screenshots.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not an expert, but reading the above answers it seemed to me that there is probably a more direct way to do this via the proc filesystem, e.g. for programmatic use in a script rather than human-readable display. And indeed there is: for a process with ID code $mypid, its child processes are listed in

```
/proc/$mypid/task/$mypid/children
```

e.g.

```
$ cat /proc/3123/task/3123/children 
3131 3133
```

Similarly, you can get the parent process ID via the "PPid" entry in the file

`/proc/$mypid/task/$mypid/status`

e.g.

```
$ grep PPid /proc/3131/task/3131/status
PPid:   3123
$ grep PPid /proc/3131/task/3131/status | cut -f2
3123
```

I'm not sure how portable this is beyond Linux systems, though.

Comment: If portability is a concern: `ps -o ppid= -o pid= -A | awk '$1 == <some pid>' | cut -f2` should be POSIX-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to see just the first-level children of a given parent process `<pid>` id look in `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/children` entry.

Note that this file contains the pids of first-level child processes. for the whole process tree, do it recursively.

this https://lwn.net/Articles/475688/ contains more information about it.