# Which command is to take for to find out about program, which else programs are initialized by this one program?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal

Yes - this concerns the question which commands in terminal are possible, for to find out which programs are initialized (visible and non-visible) - by program1. (for example - when I only want to know, which programs are running by program1 only with name "crash-handler"?) I dont mean this here:

Step 1:

```
top
```

And then step 2:

```
sudo kill -9 PID 'number-of-process'
```

I mean for to list all programs, which are running by program1 (even hidden processes ... ). This question will be rewarded with bounty! (because of thunderstorm I had amnesia and wanted to put this question earlier - this then would have prevented the stupid "hoaxes" about so-called "shell-shock-vulnerabilities" and else news ... ).

How many possible commands would be out here for this ?! (- not only htop and top and pstree ... ) - thank you !

Comment: Why is everything blockquoted? And are you looking for this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/512871/find-children-of-the-process/?

Comment: @chaos - true - this is then answered with your comment - (let this question of me out for 2 days - then you can halt it after 2 days - if necessary - but this question is thought about how many possibilites are out there ? ) - thank you -

Comment: I posted an answer listing all the ways I know. However, this is a duplicate of the linked question so I also voted to close.

Comment: Confirmed: this is a duplicate of the linked question - you're asking how to find the child processes of a master process, and that question has already been answered elsewhere,

Answer (score 3):

Try htop:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
htop
```

It has a tree view (F5) and can show all user and kernel threads (shift+H and shift+K).

Comment: thanks - sometimes my chips in my head need a re-flash -

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the various ways that can list the child processes of a given process. To my knowledge these are:

1. `top`. Launch `top` and then press <kbd>V</kbd>. From `man top`:

   ```
    ´V' :Forest-View-Mode toggle
         In  this  mode,  processes are reordered according to their
         parents and the layout of the COMMAND column resembles that
         of  a  tree.   In  forest view mode it is still possible to
         toggle between program name and commamd line (see  the  'c'
         interactive  command) or between processes and threads (see
         the 'H' interactive command).
   ```
2. `htop`. This is usually not installed by default, so install using `sudo apt-get install htop`. Then, press <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>t</kbd>. From `man htop`:

   ```
   F5, t
       Tree view: organize processes by parenthood, and layout the  rela‐
       tions between them as a tree. Toggling the key will switch between
       tree and your previously selected sort view. Selecting a sort view
       will exit tree view.
   ```
3. `pstree`. This simple command is designed for exactly that, it shows running processes as a tree.
4. `ps` itself can also do this. For example:

   ```
   $ ps -ejH
   $ ps axjf
   ```

   The important options here are `-H` for tree format and/or `-f` for full format.
5. You can also get all of this from the `/proc` filesystem if you feel like it. The children of PIDX are listed in `/proc/PIDX/task/PIDX/children`. So, you could show a tree of all running processes using

   ```
   ps ax | awk '{print $1}' | while read pid; do 
       printf "%s\n" $pid; 
       grep -o "[0-9]*" "/proc/$pid/task/$pid/children" 2>/dev/null | 
           while read cpid; do 
               printf "  |--%s\n" $cpid; 
           done
   done
   ```

   This is quite silly though since it is reinventing the wheel. Just use one of the approaches above.